# Change text in animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

As you can see here I try to show a countdown:

```
$('#countdown').text(3).fadeIn(4000).delay(500).fadeOut(4000)
               .text(2).fadeIn(4000).delay(5000).fadeOut(4000)
               .text(1).fadeIn(4000).delay(5000).fadeOut(4000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ns1ay9x6/

I do not understand, why the **animation starts at 1 instead of 3**. What do I wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `complete` callback methods of `fadeOut()` to set text. as `.delay()` only works with jQuery methods that use the animation queue on the same DOM object and `text()` don't use queue.

```
$('#countdown')
    .text(3)
    .fadeIn(4000)
    .delay(500)
    .fadeOut(4000, function() {
        $(this)
            .text(2);
    })
    .fadeIn(4000)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(4000, function() {
        $(this)
            .text(1);
    })
    .fadeIn(4000)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(4000);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tpg5k2Lt/)